# Error with DATE_DIFF in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, server-side, datediff

I keep getting an error trying to implement DATE_DIFF in mySQL.

I'm trying to get the **number of days** between "hm_date" and the present day, and have the number appear in a different field called "total_days".

Doing this on servier-side, my code is getting an error: #1305 - FUNCTION naturan8_41q.DATE_DIFF does not exist

```
SELECT * FROM reg_add WHERE DATE_DIFF(hm_date,total_days)
```

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION naturan8_41q.DATE_DIFF does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `DATE_DIFF`, thats the error. **DATEDIFF** is the correct function name.

Corrected Query: `SELECT DATEDIFF(curdate(),hm_date) as total_days FROM reg_add.`

Comment: What's this?  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as total_days LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Again....  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as total_days LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Ok.. it worked but it returned NULL's.  I changed the type to datetime.  ALL I want is a number of days.

Comment: Should hm_date be datetime as well?

Comment: Yes both fields should be datetime

Comment: both fields you are using in a date or time functions should be of datetime datatype.

Comment: hm_date equals "June 1, 2008".  I always need the field total_days to show the number of days to the present.  Is this the right approach.  I'm still getting nulls

Comment: hmdate should be in this format: 2012-05-01 and curdate will be 2012-05-11, so after applying datediff you will get: 10 as total_days.

Answer (score 2):

[`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) is the correct name, without spaces (indeed, it is confusing and inconsistent with `DATE_ADD` and `DATE_FORMAT`)

Comment: Thanks.  That worked but I got no result in total_days.  I don;t understand why.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(curdate(), hm_date) as total_days FROM reg_add
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `total_days` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1